# pushing js object to an arrays

Tags: javascript

I am working a demo react project, and got stuck to pick name and value of  js object and push to an array. which I want to use for queryparams. The js objects looks as follow

```
const ingredient = [
    { salad: 0,  bacon: 0 },
    { cheese: 0, meat: 0  }
]
```

here I want the key and the value to push to an array. ex.

```
const arrays = []
```

I try this way and did not got it correct.

```
=> for (let name of ingredient){
arrays.push(name + ingredient[name])
 }
=> arrays
 (2) ["[object Object]undefined", "[object Object]undefined"]
```

how do I push only the name and value correctly so I will able to use them in the url?

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what are you expecting in `arrays`?

Comment: `for` iterates over the `indices` of the array, not the values.  `name` is actually 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: FYI: `for (let _ in ____)` is the syntax used to iterate over *objects*.  Try it: `var foo = { a:1, b:2 };  for (let n in foo) { console.log(n); }`

Comment: Each object has two keys, so it's unclear what you want as a result.  Do you want a flattened array of every key value concatenated together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have a struct problem:
Instead of

```
const ingredient = [
    { salad: 0,  bacon: 0 },
    { cheese: 0, meat: 0  }
]
```

you should have

```
const ingredient = { salad: 0,  bacon: 0, cheese: 0, meat: 0  }
```

or

```
const ingredient = [{salade:0}, {bacon:0}, {cheese:0}, {meat:0}]
```

---

Let's say you keep only an object:

```js
const ingredient = { salad: 2,  bacon: 3, cheese: 4, meat: 0  }

let toQuery = function(obj, is_str) {
  let arr = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => { 
    acc.push(key+"="+obj[key]); 
    return acc 
  }, [])
  return is_str ? "?" + arr.join('&') : arr
}

console.log(toQuery(ingredient, false))
console.log(toQuery(ingredient, true))
```

---

Now make it works with your object (example, multi recipe)

```js
const ingredient = [{ salad: 2,  bacon: 3}, {cheese: 4, meat: 0  }]


    let toQuery = function(obj, to_str) {
      let arr = []
      obj.forEach(o => {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
          arr.push(k+"="+o[k]) 
        })
      })
      return to_str ? "?" + arr.join('&') : arr
    }

    console.log(toQuery(ingredient, false))
    console.log(toQuery(ingredient, true))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ingredient.forEach((elem) => 
{
    for(key in elem)
    {
        arrays.push(`${key}, ${elem[key]}`);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If `name` you mentioned is the `key` of object item. you can try this.

```js
const ingredient = [
    { salad: 0,  bacon: 0 },
    { cheese: 0, meat: 0  }
]

const rs = ingredient.reduce((acc, e) =>{
  for(let key in e) {
    acc.push(`${key}: ${e[key]}`)
  }
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(rs)
```